# I got error in this code when i click save then it redirects to detail page?

Tags: apex

```
public class OnlineAdmission {
public Obj_A__c A{set;get;}
public OnlineAdmission()
{
A=new Obj_A__c();
}
public pagereference save()
{
insert A;
pagereference pg=new pagereference('/apex/?id='+A.id);
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}
public void savenew()
{
insert A;
A.clear();
}
}
*************************************************************************
<apex:page controller="OnlineAdmission">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Welcome to Devry University">        
            <b>Candidate Name:</b><apex:inputText value="{!A.Candidate_Name__c}"/>
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Save&New" action="{!savenew}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>          
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: In the partial URL, the page name has to be included ('/apex/pagename?id='+A.Id) or simply ('/'+A.Id) should be given. What error is it showing?